# Django Signals check when all post_save completed and the run final function

Tags: django, post, save, signals

Is there a way to catch all post_save signals (initiated from the current request) and to check when all of them are finished? If all post_save completes then run final function.

Example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=Model1)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model2)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model3)    
def example_function(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and isinstance(instance, Model1):
        run_model1_fun()

    if created and isinstance(instance, Model2):
        run_model2_fun()

    if created and isinstance(instance, Model3):
        run_model3_fun()

   #IF all post_save completed
   run_final()
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to do that? Maybe there is a better alternative to do this...

Comment: On one request I'm working on those three models. Each model is saving int data to it self. I want to run one final function to get all int data from all three models and save it to another model.

Comment: Hm... Have you ever think about to save everything with this models, calling model methods on view, and after all at the end only call a simple method like `method_to_execute_when_everything_ends()` in your view? Signals are sync and I recommend to use only when you realy need(https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/)

Comment: Examples above are initiated on post_save with new thread, where functions are calling different APIs to sync and save specific fields data into models. Yes, It can be achieved in views too with new thread etc (as the example you have send), but I was assuming it will be easy from signal as I have all Instance data in one place and just pass needed data to API functions for check and sync to local models.

Comment: I forgot to say that I didn't show threading code in the example, but the idea is still the same. I have reviewed example and in future release I will modify the code to run in models.py as I think it will be more readable.

Comment: I think that I understand, but sorry, maybe not possible to do this. If you are trying to execute something in background, I recommend you read about celery.  (https://github.com/celery/celery)

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but unfortunately there are much more prerequisites that I do not want to implement at the moment. I'm using python threading which works very good. As regarding the issue that I have, to run final job after all post_save, still looking for a way, if not I will move to models way and define all functions there